# d3 multiline chart from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this JSON structure:

```
[{
    "city": "roma",
    "giornata": [{"hour": 0, "vscore": 2.691172504799798, "sscore": 37476.67912706408}, {"hour": 1, "vscore": 2.691172504799798, "sscore": 37476.67912706408}, {"hour": 2, "vscore": 2.6911859886310534, "sscore": 37477.76228681598}, {"hour": 3, "vscore": 2.692891756586413, "sscore": 37633.63745016247}, {"hour": 4, "vscore": 2.7490858604464163, "sscore": 40331.835034215015}, {"hour": 5, "vscore": 3.6348376398556206, "sscore": 29087.830074293775}, {"hour": 6, "vscore": 5.227711033677134, "sscore": 40951.01373374646}, {"hour": 7, "vscore": 5.437638544676074, "sscore": 41884.0578795353}, {"hour": 8, "vscore": 5.478694300536231, "sscore": 41491.303030952506}, {"hour": 9, "vscore": 5.4692759563035125, "sscore": 41406.2244628412}, {"hour": 10, "vscore": 5.443814538954288, "sscore": 41843.69307948355}, {"hour": 11, "vscore": 5.422306701744998, "sscore": 41904.21264813825}, {"hour": 12, "vscore": 5.430029861802209, "sscore": 41834.62986331701}, {"hour": 13, "vscore": 5.4109556800533065, "sscore": 41794.032135620844}, {"hour": 14, "vscore": 5.40781751131936, "sscore": 41906.699275642364}, {"hour": 15, "vscore": 5.4276853171768575, "sscore": 42204.700654376065}, {"hour": 16, "vscore": 5.431391815372439, "sscore": 42038.98228259192}, {"hour": 17, "vscore": 5.452904669522696, "sscore": 42225.77758780385}, {"hour": 18, "vscore": 5.459166165306796, "sscore": 42521.80948063545}, {"hour": 19, "vscore": 5.4113071917201605, "sscore": 42211.7148629514}, {"hour": 20, "vscore": 5.346846713801516, "sscore": 40255.25859980825}, {"hour": 21, "vscore": 5.258902353621712, "sscore": 39863.6143315623}, {"hour": 22, "vscore": 5.099446294358522, "sscore": 38595.79782658543}, {"hour": 23, "vscore": 4.825210817812031, "sscore": 35445.99667251284}],
    "totale_vscore": 4.732977155119956,
    "totale_sscore": 39994.330896155014,
    "pop": 2953570.1564810127
}, {
    "city": "milan",
    "giornata": [{"hour": 0, "vscore": 2.82848132753263, "sscore": 32951.656649915116}, {"hour": 1, "vscore": 2.989182437431815, "sscore": 22400.365091162155}, {"hour": 2, "vscore": 3.089781672302136, "sscore": 25970.908167900478}, {"hour": 3, "vscore": 3.079852593000065, "sscore": 26122.539536044023}, {"hour": 4, "vscore": 3.127878555095266, "sscore": 28533.06300816934}, {"hour": 5, "vscore": 3.433688887459625, "sscore": 31280.682050177216}, {"hour": 6, "vscore": 4.460403545073164, "sscore": 41143.18408624148}, {"hour": 7, "vscore": 4.676520890455807, "sscore": 40440.9468380336}, {"hour": 8, "vscore": 4.5650214131720945, "sscore": 40922.767810551035}, {"hour": 9, "vscore": 4.534050693834924, "sscore": 40604.83122991684}, {"hour": 10, "vscore": 4.475014854496835, "sscore": 42008.856192005565}, {"hour": 11, "vscore": 4.449355201432976, "sscore": 40234.6533377194}, {"hour": 12, "vscore": 4.479651286256149, "sscore": 42297.87576207919}, {"hour": 13, "vscore": 4.532114009807487, "sscore": 42846.236555682415}, {"hour": 14, "vscore": 4.521175500387353, "sscore": 41932.90288440584}, {"hour": 15, "vscore": 4.462502028191485, "sscore": 41718.30395828536}, {"hour": 16, "vscore": 4.46901281686112, "sscore": 41710.48122672351}, {"hour": 17, "vscore": 4.5388217291954, "sscore": 40768.24927687489}, {"hour": 18, "vscore": 4.5271592249042865, "sscore": 41346.4872610591}, {"hour": 19, "vscore": 4.525012398546656, "sscore": 40461.46407886699}, {"hour": 20, "vscore": 4.4785954581843335, "sscore": 38842.93096854251}, {"hour": 21, "vscore": 4.300929936708735, "sscore": 36595.34193318566}, {"hour": 22, "vscore": 4.157413373148136, "sscore": 34567.45808410202}, {"hour": 23, "vscore": 4.097682551344804, "sscore": 32583.34061363281}],
    "totale_vscore": 4.116637599367636,
    "totale_sscore": 37011.89694171986,
    "pop": 2228858.085428001
}]
```

I need to create a d3 line chart where every line is an element of JSON, for example:

One line for "roma" with X axis "hour" and Y axis "vscore"

Second line for "milan" with X axis "hour" and Y axis "vscore"

and so one with other cities.

My difficult is to create d3.svg.line() dynamically from json.

Now my code works with only one line:

```
    var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 40
        },
        width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 290 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);


    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .innerTickSize(-height)
        .outerTickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(10);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left").innerTickSize(-width)
        .outerTickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(10);




        // Define the line

//Here I don't know how to get line dynamically
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.hour);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.vscore);
    });


        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("#dailyChart")
            .append("svg")
            // .call(zoom)
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


                d3.json("data/ranking_sscore.json", function(error, data) {

                //Here I don't know how to cycle for get line from json

                    data = data[0].giornata

                    data.forEach(function (d) {

                            d.hour = d.hour;
                            d.vscore = +d.vscore;

                    });
                    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
                        return d.hour;
                    }))
                    y.domain([0, d3.max(data,
                        function (d) {
                            return Math.max(d.vscore);
                        })]);

                  // Add the valueline path.
                    svg.append("path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", valueline(data))
                    .style("stroke", 1);

                  // Add the X Axis
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                        .call(xAxis)
                        .selectAll("text")
                        .attr("y", 15)
                        .attr("x", 0)
                        .attr("dy", ".35em")


                    // Add the Y Axis
                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .call(yAxis);



    })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop first on your main array, then on each array "gionarta"

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 40
},
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 290 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .innerTickSize(-height)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left").innerTickSize(-width)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(10);

// Define the line

//Here I don't know how to get line dynamically
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.hour);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.vscore);
  });


// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#dailyChart")
  .append("svg")
// .call(zoom)
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



//Here is the relevant part first loop on your main array

data.forEach(function(el,index){
  items = el.giornata;
// then on each array giornata
  items.forEach(function (d) {

    d.hour = d.hour;
    d.vscore = +d.vscore;

  });
  x.domain(items.map(function (d) {
    return d.hour;
  }))
  y.domain([0, d3.max(items,
  function (d) {
    return Math.max(d.vscore);
  })]);

// Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line roma  "+data[index].city)
    .attr("d", valueline(items))
    .style("stroke", 1);

});

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")


// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
});

      
var data = [{
    "city": "roma",
    "giornata": [{"hour": 0, "vscore": 2.691172504799798, "sscore": 37476.67912706408}, {"hour": 1, "vscore": 2.691172504799798, "sscore": 37476.67912706408}, {"hour": 2, "vscore": 2.6911859886310534, "sscore": 37477.76228681598}, {"hour": 3, "vscore": 2.692891756586413, "sscore": 37633.63745016247}, {"hour": 4, "vscore": 2.7490858604464163, "sscore": 40331.835034215015}, {"hour": 5, "vscore": 3.6348376398556206, "sscore": 29087.830074293775}, {"hour": 6, "vscore": 5.227711033677134, "sscore": 40951.01373374646}, {"hour": 7, "vscore": 5.437638544676074, "sscore": 41884.0578795353}, {"hour": 8, "vscore": 5.478694300536231, "sscore": 41491.303030952506}, {"hour": 9, "vscore": 5.4692759563035125, "sscore": 41406.2244628412}, {"hour": 10, "vscore": 5.443814538954288, "sscore": 41843.69307948355}, {"hour": 11, "vscore": 5.422306701744998, "sscore": 41904.21264813825}, {"hour": 12, "vscore": 5.430029861802209, "sscore": 41834.62986331701}, {"hour": 13, "vscore": 5.4109556800533065, "sscore": 41794.032135620844}, {"hour": 14, "vscore": 5.40781751131936, "sscore": 41906.699275642364}, {"hour": 15, "vscore": 5.4276853171768575, "sscore": 42204.700654376065}, {"hour": 16, "vscore": 5.431391815372439, "sscore": 42038.98228259192}, {"hour": 17, "vscore": 5.452904669522696, "sscore": 42225.77758780385}, {"hour": 18, "vscore": 5.459166165306796, "sscore": 42521.80948063545}, {"hour": 19, "vscore": 5.4113071917201605, "sscore": 42211.7148629514}, {"hour": 20, "vscore": 5.346846713801516, "sscore": 40255.25859980825}, {"hour": 21, "vscore": 5.258902353621712, "sscore": 39863.6143315623}, {"hour": 22, "vscore": 5.099446294358522, "sscore": 38595.79782658543}, {"hour": 23, "vscore": 4.825210817812031, "sscore": 35445.99667251284}],
    "totale_vscore": 4.732977155119956,
    "totale_sscore": 39994.330896155014,
    "pop": 2953570.1564810127
}, {
    "city": "milan",
    "giornata": [{"hour": 0, "vscore": 2.82848132753263, "sscore": 32951.656649915116}, {"hour": 1, "vscore": 2.989182437431815, "sscore": 22400.365091162155}, {"hour": 2, "vscore": 3.089781672302136, "sscore": 25970.908167900478}, {"hour": 3, "vscore": 3.079852593000065, "sscore": 26122.539536044023}, {"hour": 4, "vscore": 3.127878555095266, "sscore": 28533.06300816934}, {"hour": 5, "vscore": 3.433688887459625, "sscore": 31280.682050177216}, {"hour": 6, "vscore": 4.460403545073164, "sscore": 41143.18408624148}, {"hour": 7, "vscore": 4.676520890455807, "sscore": 40440.9468380336}, {"hour": 8, "vscore": 4.5650214131720945, "sscore": 40922.767810551035}, {"hour": 9, "vscore": 4.534050693834924, "sscore": 40604.83122991684}, {"hour": 10, "vscore": 4.475014854496835, "sscore": 42008.856192005565}, {"hour": 11, "vscore": 4.449355201432976, "sscore": 40234.6533377194}, {"hour": 12, "vscore": 4.479651286256149, "sscore": 42297.87576207919}, {"hour": 13, "vscore": 4.532114009807487, "sscore": 42846.236555682415}, {"hour": 14, "vscore": 4.521175500387353, "sscore": 41932.90288440584}, {"hour": 15, "vscore": 4.462502028191485, "sscore": 41718.30395828536}, {"hour": 16, "vscore": 4.46901281686112, "sscore": 41710.48122672351}, {"hour": 17, "vscore": 4.5388217291954, "sscore": 40768.24927687489}, {"hour": 18, "vscore": 4.5271592249042865, "sscore": 41346.4872610591}, {"hour": 19, "vscore": 4.525012398546656, "sscore": 40461.46407886699}, {"hour": 20, "vscore": 4.4785954581843335, "sscore": 38842.93096854251}, {"hour": 21, "vscore": 4.300929936708735, "sscore": 36595.34193318566}, {"hour": 22, "vscore": 4.157413373148136, "sscore": 34567.45808410202}, {"hour": 23, "vscore": 4.097682551344804, "sscore": 32583.34061363281}],
    "totale_vscore": 4.116637599367636,
    "totale_sscore": 37011.89694171986,
    "pop": 2228858.085428001
}]
```

```css
.roma{
  fill:none;
  stroke:red;
}
.milan{
  fill:none;
  stroke:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="dailyChart"></div>
```

Comment: have you looked at the data, **roma** has 5.5 as max, you draw the lines with different yScales, not very correct. [correct image](https://i.imgur.com/Ck6qk5T.png)

Answer (score 3):

D3 can do the loop for you.

Here is a D3v5 version.

If you want to color many cities you can use a `color` ordinal scale, see commented line (you need to define `color`).

```js
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40 },
    svgWidth = 900,
    svgHeight = 290,
    width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = [{
    "city": "roma",
    "giornata": [
        {"hour": 0, "vscore": 2.691172504799798, "sscore": 37476.67912706408},
        {"hour": 1, "vscore": 2.691172504799798, "sscore": 37476.67912706408},
        {"hour": 2, "vscore": 2.6911859886310534, "sscore": 37477.76228681598},
        {"hour": 3, "vscore": 2.692891756586413, "sscore": 37633.63745016247},
        {"hour": 4, "vscore": 2.7490858604464163, "sscore": 40331.835034215015},
        {"hour": 5, "vscore": 3.6348376398556206, "sscore": 29087.830074293775},
        {"hour": 6, "vscore": 5.227711033677134, "sscore": 40951.01373374646},
        {"hour": 7, "vscore": 5.437638544676074, "sscore": 41884.0578795353},
        {"hour": 8, "vscore": 5.478694300536231, "sscore": 41491.303030952506},
        {"hour": 9, "vscore": 5.4692759563035125, "sscore": 41406.2244628412},
        {"hour": 10, "vscore": 5.443814538954288, "sscore": 41843.69307948355},
        {"hour": 11, "vscore": 5.422306701744998, "sscore": 41904.21264813825},
        {"hour": 12, "vscore": 5.430029861802209, "sscore": 41834.62986331701},
        {"hour": 13, "vscore": 5.4109556800533065, "sscore": 41794.032135620844},
        {"hour": 14, "vscore": 5.40781751131936, "sscore": 41906.699275642364},
        {"hour": 15, "vscore": 5.4276853171768575, "sscore": 42204.700654376065},
        {"hour": 16, "vscore": 5.431391815372439, "sscore": 42038.98228259192},
        {"hour": 17, "vscore": 5.452904669522696, "sscore": 42225.77758780385},
        {"hour": 18, "vscore": 5.459166165306796, "sscore": 42521.80948063545},
        {"hour": 19, "vscore": 5.4113071917201605, "sscore": 42211.7148629514},
        {"hour": 20, "vscore": 5.346846713801516, "sscore": 40255.25859980825},
        {"hour": 21, "vscore": 5.258902353621712, "sscore": 39863.6143315623},
        {"hour": 22, "vscore": 5.099446294358522, "sscore": 38595.79782658543},
        {"hour": 23, "vscore": 4.825210817812031, "sscore": 35445.99667251284}],
    "totale_vscore": 4.732977155119956,
    "totale_sscore": 39994.330896155014,
    "pop": 2953570.1564810127
}, {
    "city": "milan",
    "giornata": [
        {"hour": 0, "vscore": 2.82848132753263, "sscore": 32951.656649915116},
        {"hour": 1, "vscore": 2.989182437431815, "sscore": 22400.365091162155},
        {"hour": 2, "vscore": 3.089781672302136, "sscore": 25970.908167900478},
        {"hour": 3, "vscore": 3.079852593000065, "sscore": 26122.539536044023},
        {"hour": 4, "vscore": 3.127878555095266, "sscore": 28533.06300816934},
        {"hour": 5, "vscore": 3.433688887459625, "sscore": 31280.682050177216},
        {"hour": 6, "vscore": 4.460403545073164, "sscore": 41143.18408624148},
        {"hour": 7, "vscore": 4.676520890455807, "sscore": 40440.9468380336},
        {"hour": 8, "vscore": 4.5650214131720945, "sscore": 40922.767810551035},
        {"hour": 9, "vscore": 4.534050693834924, "sscore": 40604.83122991684},
        {"hour": 10, "vscore": 4.475014854496835, "sscore": 42008.856192005565},
        {"hour": 11, "vscore": 4.449355201432976, "sscore": 40234.6533377194},
        {"hour": 12, "vscore": 4.479651286256149, "sscore": 42297.87576207919},
        {"hour": 13, "vscore": 4.532114009807487, "sscore": 42846.236555682415},
        {"hour": 14, "vscore": 4.521175500387353, "sscore": 41932.90288440584},
        {"hour": 15, "vscore": 4.462502028191485, "sscore": 41718.30395828536},
        {"hour": 16, "vscore": 4.46901281686112, "sscore": 41710.48122672351},
        {"hour": 17, "vscore": 4.5388217291954, "sscore": 40768.24927687489},
        {"hour": 18, "vscore": 4.5271592249042865, "sscore": 41346.4872610591},
        {"hour": 19, "vscore": 4.525012398546656, "sscore": 40461.46407886699},
        {"hour": 20, "vscore": 4.4785954581843335, "sscore": 38842.93096854251},
        {"hour": 21, "vscore": 4.300929936708735, "sscore": 36595.34193318566},
        {"hour": 22, "vscore": 4.157413373148136, "sscore": 34567.45808410202},
        {"hour": 23, "vscore": 4.097682551344804, "sscore": 32583.34061363281}],
    "totale_vscore": 4.116637599367636,
    "totale_sscore": 37011.89694171986,
    "pop": 2228858.085428001
}];

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(-height);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .tickSize(-width);

var valueline = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x( d => x(d.hour) )
    .y( d => y(d.vscore) );

// Adds the svg canvas
var g = d3.select("#dailyChart")
    .append("svg")
    // .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// d3.json("data/ranking_sscore.json", drawGraph );

drawGraph(null, data);

function drawGraph(error, data) {

    x.domain(d3.extent(data[0].giornata, d => d.hour));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.max(d.giornata, g => g.vscore) ) + 1 ]);

    // Add the X Axis
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("y", 15)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("dy", ".35em");

    // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    g.selectAll(".city")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr('class', d => 'city' + ' ' + d.city)
       //.style("stroke", (d,i) => color(i) )
       .attr("d", d => valueline(d.giornata) );
}
```

```css
.roma {
  fill:none;
  stroke:red;
}
.milan {
  fill:none;
  stroke:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="dailyChart"></div>
```

Comment: I guess that should have been the correct/accepted answer